# Add Windows Feature from C#

Tags: c#, .net, iis, iis-7

As part of an installation package I'm working on, I need to add the IIS feature on Win7 and Win Server 2008.
Is there any way of adding new windows features from code?

Comment: What installer software are you using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this by calling [`pkgmgr`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc749465%28WS.10%29.aspx) (a command line utility for installing features and packages).

There is an example of how to do this for MSMQ here:

- [Install Msmq using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6679084/install-msmq-using-c)

Comment: I like that that's a link to another Stackoverflow question to which the excepted answer is a link to *another* Stackoverflow question - very meta.

Comment: @Martin My aim is one day to create a circular reference where none of the answers actually answers the question.