# Are there alternatives to using PowerShell in a .NET Core application to manage WindowsFeatures?

Tags: c#, windows, powershell, .net-core

I have a .NET Core application that utilizes the PowerShell libraries (`System.Management.Automation`) to Get / Install / Uninstall-WindowsFeature on Windows Server machines. The equivalent on non-server machines is to use Get / Add / Remove-Capability.

For a variety of reasons I am investigating alternative methods for replicating the above functionality without using Powershell in our application.

Are there other alternative libraries available (either commercial or OpenSource)? Are there .NET or Win32 Api/libraries that could be leveraged?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8054282/how-can-you-programmatically-turn-off-or-on-windows-features and links there for more details about dism or alternatives

Comment: @Dallas - Thanks for the reply. Working on a more secure Windows machine, DISM/Powershell might be disabled/removed/restricted in access. Is it possible to manage Windows Features directly through .Net libraries or Win32 API?

Comment: So no CMD or using servermanger either I assume?    There is a DISM COM API I think that only needs System.Runtime.InteropServices .  Might that be an option if DISM isn't?    There must be something in .NET to get/set Win32_OptionalFeature class though I would think.