# How to enable MSMQ programmatically in C#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, client-server, msmq

I have a server with a request queue and a client with a responsive queue.
I want to install MSMQ pragmatically on client as well as on server machine i.e. not by manually going to Server Manager/Add window's features.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Install Msmq using C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6679084/install-msmq-using-c-sharp)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can start

```
dism.exe /Online /Enable-Feature /FeatureName:MSMQ-Server /all
```

as a process using:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start()
```

If you need any aditionally Msmq features, you can find list this by doing:

```
dism.exe /online /get-features | Find "MSMQ"
```

which gives you something like:

```
Feature Name : MSMQ-Container
Feature Name : MSMQ-Server
Feature Name : MSMQ-Triggers
Feature Name : MSMQ-ADIntegration
Feature Name : MSMQ-HTTP
Feature Name : MSMQ-Multicast
Feature Name : MSMQ-DCOMProxy
Feature Name : WCF-MSMQ-Activation45
```

Comment: I got error of "You cannot run a 32 bit of dism service on 64 bit machine 32 bit of dism"

Comment: There is no 'dism.exe' in 'system' folder it is only in 'system32'. I have to run it from 64 bit system folder i.e. 'system'.

Comment: @operation check in your c:\Windows\SysWow64 folder

Comment: @operation, according to a blog (See below) the error message "Error: 11 You cannot service a running 64-bit operating system with a 32-bit version of DISM" indicates that you should explicitly use the \system32\dism.exe version, weird :)

http://kwsupport.com/2013/04/dism-for-windows-server-2008-r2-64-bit/

Comment: c:\Windows\SysWow64 folder does not have 'dism.exe'